# Spring Security 5 client credenital grant with azure ad

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I have spring boot service A secured with spring security server config

```
spring:
    security:
      oauth2:
        resourceserver:
          jwt:
            issuer-uri: https://sts.windows.net/****-azure-tenant-id-***/
        client:
          provider:
            azure-ad:
              issuer-uri: https://sts.windows.net/****-azure-tenant-id-***/
audience-id: ****-resource-id-****
```

SecurityConfiguration

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${audience-id}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure-ad.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Autowired
    ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Bean
    @Order(10)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain oAuth2SecurityWebFilter(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/**"))
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtDecoder(jwtDecoder)
                .and()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder() {
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, new AudienceValidator(audience));

        NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder = (NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder) ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuer);
        reactiveJwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
        return reactiveJwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

So this app is secured and requires a bearer token with resource id `****-resource-id-****` to access the apis.

I have another service B that talks to this service A with client credential grant

```
spring:
   security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          provider:
            azure-ad:
              token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/***-tenant-id-**/oauth2/token
          registration:
            azure-ad:
              authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
              client-id: ****-resource-id-****
              client-secret: ****-client-seret-***
```

Webclient configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository, new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("azure-ad");
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
}
```

When call is from service B to service A is made by autowiring webclient, webclient is sending a bearer token but that bearer is not for the service A's resource id and failing with 403 forbidden.
How to configure webclient to request token for service A's resource id?

Comment: Hi @user09, can I have the complete example of this implementation. Actually I am also implementing the same thing with azure AD and spring security but doesn't found any complete example like if we need to add annotations on controllers or somewhere. 
So can you please help me for this by letting me know link where I can find complete implementation example??

Answer (score 1):

Service to service calls using client credentials (shared secret or certificate)

Azure AD also allows the calling service to use a certificate (instead of a shared secret) as a credential

Access token request with a certificate

HTTP POST requests an access token for the https://service.contoso.com/ web service with a certificate. The client_id identifies the web service that requests the access token.

```html
POST /contoso.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=625bc9f6-3bf6-4b6d-94ba-e97cf07a22de&client_secret=qkDwDJlDfig2IpeuUZYKH1Wb8q1V0ju6sILxQQqhJ+s=&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
```

Reference to Use the access token to access the secured resource & Access token request with a shared secret

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow